# Unable to copy from vim to system clipboard

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gvim, clipboard

I read and tried several different solutions but I am still unable to copy from vim to system clipboard. Viceversa works, copying from outside vim and pasting with p is ok.

I have installed clipboard support, vim version is 7.3.429:

```
$ vim --version | grep clip
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
```

I have:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

in my `.vimrc` and clipboard is set when I do:

```
set clipboard?
```

(that returns `clipboard=unnamedplus`)
or

```
:echo has('clipboard')
```

`:echo has('unnamedplus')` returns 1

To copy from gvim to clipboard I am using:

```
yy
y
"*y
"+y
```

To paste I use `Ctrl+V`, `Ctrl+Shift+V` (in a terminal), but it doesn't work.

My `vimrc` is [here](http://pastebin.com/qyCVEacL) (sorry for pastebin, it is too long to stay in this post)

Edit: copying to different instance of vim works, via the p shortcut. Otherwise it does not work.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and GVim. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What does "`:echo has('unnamedplus')`" show?  Also, are you sure you want 'clipboard' to be set to "unnamedplus" and not just "unnamed"?  What are you doing to try to copy to the clipboard?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: What about `"+y`? What do you use to paste in other programs? `<C-v>`? Middle-click?

Comment: It doesn't work.. I use `Ctrl+V`, `Ctrl+Shift+V` (in a terminal)..

Comment: I have the same problem with my debian 7 server. I connect using SSH from my ubuntu desktop. On other (centos) servers vim copying works normally.

Comment: @Francesco try pasting via middle-click. If this works, your real problem is how to synchronize both clipboards.

Comment: It does not work, neither with middle-click nor `Ctrl-insert`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, using Ubuntu 12.04, I found answer [in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/434994/52284)

Basically you have to install `vim-gtk`.

Comment: vim-gtk is installed. Vim has +clipboard. "+y and "*y don't affect the clipboard contents at all. (Ubuntu 18.04)